# Where is the "2+2" in this Assembly code (translated by gcc from C)

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I've written this simple C code

```
int main()
{
    int calc = 2+2;
    return 0;
}
```

And I want to see how that looks in assembly, so I compiled it using `gcc`

```
$ gcc -S -o asm.s test.c
```

And the result was ~65 lines (Mac OS X 10.8.3) and I only found these to be related:

[image]

Where do I look for my `2+2` in this code?

#### Edit:

One part of the question hasn't been addressed.

If `%rbp, %rsp, %eax` are variables, what values do they attain in this case?

Comment: The compiler has almost certainly just moved `4` directly into `calc`.

Comment: Note that further optimization may even wipe out `calc` entirely, since it's not referenced in the body of the function anywhere

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Almost all of the code you got is just useless stack manipulation.  With optimization on (`gcc -S -O2 test.c`) you will get something like

```
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
```

Ignore every line that starts with a dot or ends with a colon: there are only two assembly instructions:

```
    xorl %eax, %eax
    ret
```

and they encode `return 0;`.  (XORing a register with itself sets it to all-bits-zero.  Function return values go in register `%eax` per the x86 ABI.)  Everything to do with your `int calc = 2+2;` has been discarded as unused.

If you changed your code to

```
int main(void) { return 2+2; }
```

you would instead get

```
    movl $4, %eax
    ret
```

where the 4 comes from the compiler doing the addition itself rather than making the generated program do it (this is called [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding)).

Perhaps more interesting is if you change the code to

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) { return argc + 2; }
```

then you get

```
    leal    2(%rdi), %eax
    ret
```

which is doing some real work at runtime! In the 64-bit ELF ABI, `%rdi` holds the first argument to the function, `argc` in this case.  `leal 2(%rdi), %eax` is x86 assembly language for "`%eax = %edi + 2`" and it's being done this way mainly because the more familiar `add` instruction takes only two arguments, so you can't use it to add 2 to `%rdi` and put the result in `%eax` all in one instruction.  (Ignore the difference between `%rdi` and `%edi` for now.)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to optimisation and how to evaluate `.\:`, this answered a few followup questions I had.

Answer (score 10):

The compiler determined that `2+2 = 4` and inlined it.  The constant is stored in line 10 (the `$4`).  To verify this, change the math to `2+3` and you will see `$5`

EDIT: as for the registers themselves, `%rsp` is the stack pointer, `%rbp` is the frame pointer, and `%eax` is a general register

Comment: You're right, it does change into `$5`, but why then all the extra code? And my question about these `%rbp, %rsp, %eax` values?

Comment: @MorganWilde `%rsp` is the stack pointer, `%rbp` is the frame pointer, and `%eax` is a general register

Answer (score 2):

Your program has no observable behavior, which means that in general case the compiler might not generate any machine code for it at all, besides some minimal startup-wrapup instructions intended to ensure that zero is returned to the calling environment. At least declare your variable as `volatile`. Or print its value after evaluating it. Or return it from `main`.

Also note that in C language `2 + 2` qualifies as *integral constant expression*. This means that compiler is not just *allowed*, but actually *required* to know the result of that expression *at compile time*. Taking this into account, it would be strange to expect the compiler to evaluate `2 + 2` at run time when the final value is known at compile time (even if you completely disable optimizations).

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I was not aware that this was the case, I.e. compiler doing some of the calculations at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an explanation of the assembly code:

```
pushq    %rbp
```

This saves a copy of the frame pointer on the stack. The function itself does not need this; it is there so that debuggers or exception handlers can find frames on the stack.

```
movq     %rsp, %rbp
```

This starts a new frame by setting the frame pointer to point to the current top-of-stack. Again, the function does not need this; it is housekeeping to maintain a proper stack.

```
mov      $4, -12(%rbp)
```

Here the compiler initializes `calc` to 4. Several things have happened here. First, the compiler evaluated `2+2` by itself and used the result, 4, in the assembly code. The arithmetic is not performed in the executing program; it was completed in the compiler. Second, `calc` has been assigned the location 12 bytes below the frame pointer. (This is interesting because it is also below the stack pointer. The OS X ABI for this architecture includes a “red zone” below the stack pointer that programs are permitted to use, which is unusual.) Third, the program was clearly compiled without optimization. We know that because the optimizer would recognize that this code has no effect and is useless, so it would remove it.

```
movl     $0, -8(%rbp)
```

This code stores 0 in the place the compiler has set aside to prepare the return value of `main`.

```
movl     -8(%rbp), %eax
movl     %eax, -4(%rbp)
```

This copies data from the place where the return value is prepared to a temporary handling location. This is even more useless than the previous code, reinforcing the conclusion that optimization was not used. This looks like code I would expect at a negative optimization level.

```
movl     -4(%rbp), %eax
```

This moves the return value from the temporary handling location to the register in which it is returned to the caller.

```
popq      %rbp
```

This restores the frame pointer, thus removing the previously-pushed frame from the stack.

```
ret
```

This puts the program out of its misery.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler optimized it away, it pre-computed the answer and just set the result.  If you want to see the compiler do the add then you cannot let it "see" the constants you are feeding it

If you compile this code all by itself as an object (gcc -O2 -c test_add.c -o test_add.o)
then you will force the compiler to generate the add code.  But the operands will be registers or on the stack.

```
int test_add ( int a, int b )
{
   return(a+b);
}
```

Then if you call it from code in a separate source (gcc -O2 -c test.c -o test.o) then you will see the two operands be forced into the function.

```
extern int test_add ( int, int );
int test ( void )
{
     return(test_add(2,2));
}
```

and you can disassemble both of those objects (objdump -D test.o, objdump -D test_add.o)

When you do something that simple in one file

```
int main ( void )
{
     int a,b,c;
     a=2;
     b=2;
     c=a+b;
     return(0);
}
```

The compiler can optimize your code into one of a few equivalents.  My example here, does nothing, the math and results have no purpose, they are not used, so they can simply be removed as dead code.  Your opitmization did this

```
int main ( void )
{
     int c;
     c=4;
     return(0);
}
```

But this is also a perfectly valid optimization of the above code

```
int main ( void )
{
    return(0);
}
```

EDIT:

Where is the calc=2+2?

I believe the

```
movl $4,-12(%rbp)
```

Is the 2+2 (the answer is computed and simply placed in calc which is on the stack.

```
movl $0,-8(%rbp)
```

I assume is the 0 in your return(0);

The actual math of adding two numbers was optimized out.

Answer (score 0):

I guess line 10, he optimzed since all are constants